# how to read item template field in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one dropdown box inside the item template. As per of my requirement I need to update the tooltip field of drop down in aspx.cs page.

I use the following code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid-label-small" HeaderText="*State">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDefState" Width="110px" runat="server" ToolTip="Select State">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-label-small" />
</asp:TemplateField>`.
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can find the Item template control using this assuming you are binding in RowDataBound event. Add OnRowDataBound event to GridView like this,

```
<asp:GridView runat="server"   OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound"  ></asp:GridView>

protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
     DropDownList dropDown;

     dropDown= e.Row.FindControl("ddlDefState") as DropDownList;

      if (dropDown!= null)
        // Write your code here            
    }
}
```

Optionally, you may also be able to bind to tooltip from asp:GridView markup in this way,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid-label-small" HeaderText="*State">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDefState" Width="110px" runat="server" 
    ToolTip="<%# Bind("Your Property Name") %>">
</asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-label-small" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Can I know where I can call the function grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
?

Comment: is there any way to change the tooltip text without using grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Use RowDataBound Event of GridView as:

```
void TitleGridView_RowDataBound (Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    // Get the RadioButtonList control from the row.
    RadioButtonList radio = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("TypeList");

   // To Get DropDownList Cast as DropDownList and Find with it's Id - ddlDefState
  DropDownList list = (DropDownList )e.Row.FindControl("ddlDefState");
```

Check this [TemplateField.ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.itemtemplate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Property for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Handle an event `RowDataBound` for the GridView like:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gvData" OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound">
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-label-small" />
  <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid-label-small" HeaderText="*State">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDefState" Width="110px" runat="server" 
       ToolTip="Select State">
     </asp:DropDownList>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now, at event `gvData_RowDataBound` find the `dropdown` and change the `tooltip` as:

```
protected void gvData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddlDefState;
        ddlDefState = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlDefState");
        if (ddlDefState != null)
        {
            ddlDefState.ToolTip = "Your New Tooltips";
            // Write your other code here            
        }
    }
}
```